# Pre-run "cancellation" in bareos/bacula

Tags: scripting, bacula, bareos

DNS in my environment is a bit wonky at times. When Bareos connects to a client, the client is not always the one specified by the hostname. I have a cron script that runs jobs automatically and checks to see if the host and fd on the client match, but I'm wondering if there's a way to put a pre-run script that cancels a manually run job if the same info does not match.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Put a different bacula-fd password for different clients.

Then, if DNS points to wrong client, it will be unable to connect and abort automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use client initiated connection. If you configure it correctly only the bareos-fd will open a connection to the director making it unlikely to connect to the wrong host.

Also, make sure you use different passwords for different bareos-fds.